# Obtener el valor de un textbox que esta dentro de un GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, gridview

Tenemos un proyecto de la universidad, el cual consiste en un carrito de compra. El problema esta que en un GridView que estamos llenando con una tabla de la BD, hemos colocado un TextBox para que ellos escojan la cantidad de productos que quisieran comprar. EL problema viene que no sabemos como obtener la propiedad TEXT de dicho textbox.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="Nombre" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Precio" HeaderText="Precio" SortExpression="Precio" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" SortExpression="Descripcion" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtCantidad" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>                      
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAgregar" CssClass="" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Nombre")+ "::" +Eval("Precio")%>' Text="Agregar" OnClick="btnAgregar_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>

        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

El TextBox con el ID txtCantidad, no sabemos como obtener o capturar lo que escriban dentro de el, asi para luego hacer una simple multipicacion con la columna Precio y la cantidad introducidad.

En el evento del boton btnAgregar solo hemos podido capturar lo siguiente:

```
protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string precio;
    string nombre, cantidad;
    LinkButton btnAgregar = (LinkButton)sender;

    string[] ar = btnAgregar.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    precio = ar[1];
    nombre = ar[0];
}
```

Les agradeceriamos mucho si nos ayudaran con este problema ya que vamos iniciando y no conocemos a profundidad el lenguaje. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento rowcommand de tu gridview y asignar un commandname a tu linkbutton:

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAgregar" runat="server" Text="Agregar" CommandName="Agregar" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

En el código del rowcommand:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Agregar")
  {
     //Primero capturas la fila
     int numFila= ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent).RowIndex;

     //Buscas el control ubicandolo por fila y columna, y lo agregas a un textbox  
     TextBox txtValor = (GridView1.Rows[numFila].Cells[4].FindControl("txtCantidad") as TextBox);

     //Obtienes el valor del textbox    
     string cantidad=txtValor.Text; 

     //Obtienes el nombre y precio de los boundfield
     string nombre=(GridView1.Rows[numFila].Cells[1].Text);  
     string precio=(GridView1.Rows[numFila].Cells[2].Text);     
  }
}
```